# Dropwizard metrics to track zip codes in an incoming request

Tags: java, dropwizard, metrics, grafana, prometheus

I am working on an application that accepts incoming HTTP requests and contains the user's zip code. I would like to track each of the zip codes received using a metric such that it can be reported to Prometheus and graphed inside Grafana. It would not make sense to have a counter for every single zip code but I worry that a Gauge would not be appropriate and Grafana would miss some of the data between Prometheus scrapes. Any suggestions for how I could possibly accomplish this task? We do have logging but we need this information displayed in Grafana.

Comment: I think this is a usecase for a counter. In DW, just get-or-create it with your namespace + zip code, like: `com.christ.montaya.tracker.zip.<actual_zip_code>`  - you can then (not sure about your tools) wildcard a graph for `com.christ.montaya.tracker.zip.*` which plots all different zipcodes in 1 graph displaying the amount of requests per zip code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a use case for logging than metrics given the cardinality.

This is a use case for a label, however Dropwizard doesn't support those. Thus if you're going to do this with Prometheus I'd suggest using the [Java client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) with a `Counter` with a label for the zip code.